# I am not able to remove subView in detailView from rootViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have multiple detail Views, when i click on select second row in my rootViewController, i remove the detailView and add a newView from the appDelegate. When i do this im not able to send value from rootView to newDetailView.
this is what i do in my appdelegate

```
    [splitViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    arcObj = [[Architecture alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:arcObj];
    [arcObj release];
    splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController,detailNav,nil];
    splitViewController.delegate=arcObj;
```

in rootVeiwController

```
NewdetailViewController.detailItem = @"gettingin";
```

In my newDetailView

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem {
if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    [detailItem release];
    detailItem = [newDetailItem retain];
}}
```

its not calling the method

```
 - (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
```

any help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use -

```
[NewdetailViewControllerObject setDetailItem:@"gettingin"];
```

Comment: I tried that also...its not working,...what could be the mistake?

Comment: You need to call it by object not by Class , as it is not class method. I think that's the issue. Editing my answer.

Comment: yes thats what i said, NewdetailViewControllerObject is the object of class NewdetailViewController.

Comment: no its not working my friend...thats what im not understanding the mistake.... :(